# Get data from sql server to appear on Kendo Scheduler

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I want to know how I can get the information that I have on a sql table into a Kendo scheduler. What I currently have in the server is the Start, End, StartTimeZone, EndTimeZone, Description, Title... etc. All the stuff you need for Kendo Scheduler, but I have many events that I need to make and put into a calendar format and the scheduler seems like the best way to do it. Right now my calendar view looks like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<**censored**.Models.LeaveRequest>()

.Name("scheduler")
.Date(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13))
.StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 7, 00, 00))
.Height(600)
.Views(views =>
{
    views.DayView();
    views.WeekView();
    views.MonthView(MonthView => MonthView.Selected(true));
})
.Timezone("Etc/UTC")
.DataSource(d => d
    .Model(m =>
    {

        m.Id(f => f.LeaveRequestId);
        m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
        m.Field(f => f.EmployeeId).DefaultValue(1);
        m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
        m.RecurrenceId(f => f.LeaveRequestId);
    })
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home").Data("getAdditionalData"))
    .Create("Create", "Home")
    .Destroy("Destroy", "Home")
    .Update("Update", "Home")
)
    )

    <script>

function getAdditionalData() {
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

    var timezone = scheduler.options.timezone;
    var startDate = kendo.timezone.convert(scheduler.view().startDate(), timezone, "Etc/UTC");
    var endDate = kendo.timezone.convert(scheduler.view().endDate(), timezone, "Etc/UTC");

    //optionally add startTime / endTime of the view
    var startTime = kendo.date.getMilliseconds(scheduler.view().startTime());
    var endTime = kendo.date.getMilliseconds(scheduler.view().endTime());
    endTime = endTime == 0 ? kendo.date.MS_PER_DAY : endTime;

    var result = {
        Start: new Date(startDate.getTime() - (startDate.getTimezoneOffset() * kendo.date.MS_PER_MINUTE) + startTime),
        End: new Date(endDate.getTime() - (endDate.getTimezoneOffset() * kendo.date.MS_PER_MINUTE) + endTime)
    }

    return result;
}
    </script>
    <style>
        .invalid-slot {
            background: red !important;
            cursor: no-drop;
        }
    </style>


</div>
```

But I don't know what I need to do in the controllers and models, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

I just completed the implementation of KendoUI Scheduler by integrating it with SQL data base. However, I made use of JavaScript API to do so in my MVC project.

To load the data i.e. "read" and perform insert, update and delete just return the model in JSON format from controller. The Scheduler will bind the data for you, if it gets the **"know"** format.

```
return Json(**censored**.Models.LeaveRequest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Couple of important points:
1. KendoUI Scheduler depends a lot on unique id, so in case you have anything other than "id" - then **"do"** configure it in your scheduler.
In JS API it was done using following syntax, where EventID was the unique ID my SQL table.

```
schema: {
   model: {
        "id": "EventID",
        "fields": {
            "EventID": {
                "type": "number"
            },
....
```

2. Always return JSON data from your Insert, Update and Delete method from Controller. For instance:

   public JsonResult UpdateCalendarEvent(string models)
   {
   ...
   return Json(**censored**.Models.LeaveRequest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
   }
3. In case of Insert, before returning the JSON object, do update the ID or EventID with latest row id, so Scheduler will sync up all data on client side and can perform update and delete operation appropriately.

Hope that helps!